# How get curlpp response header

Tags: c++, curl, http-headers, httpresponse, curlpp

I'm calling a REST WS with a JSON payload to subscribe certains events. The server answer with HTTP-Code 201 and a field named **Location** in the HTTP-Header with the ID of the subscription.

As an example, in curl (-v) we get:

```
[...]
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: /v2/subscriptions/5ab386ad4bf6feec37ffe44d
[...]
```

In C++ using curlpp we want to retrieve that id looking at the response header. Now we have only the body response (in this case empty).

```
std::ostringstream response;
subRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(&response));

// Send request and get a result.
subRequest.perform();

cout << response.str() << endl;
```

How can we obtain the **Location** header's field (whose content in the example is "/v2/subscriptions/5ab386ad4bf6feec37ffe44d") in C++ using curlpp?

Comment: NOTE: Redirecting cout and cerr doesn't seems work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several values you can retrieve using the family of `curlpp::infos::*::get` functions. For example the HTTP response code:

```
curlpp::infos::ResponseCode::get(subRequest)
```

See the [Infos.hpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/include/curlpp/Infos.hpp) header for a complete list. When you need a value that is not available through one of these infos you can also choose to receive the headers separately from the body in a callback.

```
subRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HeaderFunction(
    [] (char* buffer, size_t size, size_t items) -> size_t {
        std::string s(buffer, size * items); // buffer is not null terminated
        std::cout << s;
        return size * items;
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it.

Simply adding

```
subRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Header(1));
```

do the trick and stores headers in the response.